# Excel: "Don't display alert and don't update links" inside a macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have created a macro to create a new excel file out of the master file I am using but without any links and macros. The purpose of the new file is that it will contain all the data/values from the master file but no links/formula/macro. And the new file also should not show the message of 'update links' while opening.

What I am doing so far is after the creation of the new file I am clicking on 'Break Link' and then 'selecting don't display the alert and don't update automatic links' from the Startup Prompt.

Is there a way to do the above (break link and don't display ...) steps using vba within the new file creating macro?

Comment: This isn't a free code writing service.  Post what you have done so far and people may be willing to help to point you in the right direction.